# When creating a PictureBox in an array it does not show up on my Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I created an array of `PictureBox` objects in my code like so:

```
        PictureBox[] picturbox = new PictureBox[100];
```

Then I have this in Form's load code:

```
    picturbox[1] = new PictureBox();
    picturbox[1].Image = Properties.Resources.img1;
    picturbox[1].Visible = true;
    picturbox[1].Location = new Point(0, 0);
    this.Size = new Size(800, 600);
    picturbox[1].Size = new Size(800, 600);
```

However, the `PictureBox` does not appear on the Form. When I do exact same command with `PictureBox` that was created by Drag & Drop, it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the pictureBox to the Form:

```
this.Controls.Add(picturebox[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add each PictureBox to the form's Controls.

```
foreach(var box in picturbox)
    this.Controls.Add(box)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did not add picture box, check the `InitializeComponent();` method. It is positioned at the top of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This works just as well:

```
this.Controls.AddRange(picturebox);
```

---

For a collection that isn't an array use this:

```
this.Controls.AddRange(picturebox.ToArray());
```