# Making an array of pictureboxes, each with different images

Tags: c#, image, resources

I have 100 files in Resources named "1.png", "2.png". I have a `PictureBox[]` array generated with code, and I want to set `array[i].Image = string.Format("Properties.Resources.{0}.png", i);` But this does not work.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Reflection, Something like following would do the task:

```
var properties = typeof(Properties.Resources).GetProperties
    (BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

PictureBox[] array = new PictureBox[100];
int counter = 0;
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    var image = property.GetValue(null, null) as System.Drawing.Bitmap;
    if (image != null && counter < array.Length)
    {
        array[counter] = new PictureBox();
        array[counter++].Image = image;
    }
}
```

Remember to include `using System.Reflection;` at the top.

Answer (score 3):

If your images have names that conform to some pattern inside the resource file (like "Image1", "Image2", etc.), you may load them by their names:

```
ResourceManager rm = Resources.ResourceManager;
array[i].Image = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(string.Format("Image{0}", i));
```

Comment: ResourceManager cannot be used like this. Sorry for the -1. Wanted to give you +1 for using ResourceManager but then i saw that your code is suggesting something which does not work. Cannot set this to 0 again.

Comment: @wonko79: Oops! Lost .GetObject call.

Answer (score 2):

you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233434/when-creating-a-picturebox-in-an-array-it-does-not-show-up-on-my-form) post.

or you can simply use :

```
array[i].Image = Properties.Resources.img1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace your_name_project
{
    public partial class Form_Begin : Form
    {
        PictureBox[] pictureBoxs = new PictureBox[6];
        public Form_Begin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pictureBoxs[0] = pictureBox1; pictureBoxs[1] = pictureBox2; pictureBoxs[2] = pictureBox3;
            pictureBoxs[3] = pictureBox4; pictureBoxs[4] = pictureBox5;   pictureBoxs[5] = pictureBox6;     
        }
//continue 
        List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox>();

            private void buttonX1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <3; i++)
                {
                    pictureBoxs[i].Image =your_name_project.Properties.Resources.image_1;// load image1 and Image_2from resource in property of picturebox  
                }
                for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    pictureBoxs[i].Image = your_name_project.Properties.Resources.Image_2;
                }
            } 
        }
}
```